# Understanding the "using" statement in asp.net 4.0 - C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, using

Are there any difference between these 2 codes ?  Which one should be used ?

asp.net 4.0 , c#

code 1 :

```
using System;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public static class DbConnection
{
    public static string srConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=mydb;uid=sa;pwd=mypw;";

    public static DataSet db_Select_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, connection);
                DA.Fill(dSet);
            }
            return dSet;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (srConnectionString.IndexOf("select Id from tblAspErrors") != -1)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    strQuery = strQuery.Replace("'", "''");
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into tblSqlErrors values ('" + strQuery + "')", connection);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            return dSet;
        }
    }

    public static void db_Update_Delete_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            strQuery = strQuery.Replace("'", "''");
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into tblSqlErrors values ('" + strQuery + "')", connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

code 2 :

```
using System;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public static class DbConnection
{
    public static string srConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=mydb;uid=sa;pwd=mypw;";

    public static DataSet db_Select_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, connection))
                {
                    DA.Fill(dSet);
                }
            }
            return dSet;
        }

        catch
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                if (srConnectionString.IndexOf("select Id from tblAspErrors") != -1)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    strQuery = strQuery.Replace("'", "''");

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into tblSqlErrors values ('" + strQuery + "')", connection))
                    {
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            return dSet;
        }
    }

    public static void db_Update_Delete_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            strQuery = strQuery.Replace("'", "''");
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into tblSqlErrors values ('" + strQuery + "')", connection))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with either example? Sorry, the code examples are too long to skim for what the difference is.

Comment: look inside try blocks. which one is better or any difference ?

Comment: `using` is a language keyword. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET

Comment: I've found it, but you should really try and reduce the code examples in your questions to the relevant parts instead of including whole source files - your question essentially boils down to "do I have to use `using` with SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter?" but it takes effort to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ReSharper to do it for you or are willing to download them manually, you could look at the source code for `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` and see if their Dispose() method actually does anything. If not, it's probably safe to leave out the using statements around them.

Comment: actually i wonder this. only having parent using statement is better or having nested using statements.

Comment: You have to use `using` for *every* object you want to/have to `Dispose()` automatically. Wrapping a function in a `using` block does not automatically dispose everything inside that block, only the object in the parens.

Comment: so it only dispose of objects inside () instead of {} right ?

Comment: i got it now. so second coding is better

Comment: @Sii, did you mean if the Dispose method of SqlCommand or SqlDataAdapter does something, no need to use a using block?

Comment: @IrishChieftain: No, the opposite - if their `Dispose()` does *nothing*, you do *not* need a `using` block. (If it does *something*, it *should* be called, and you *should* use a `using` block.) SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter implement IDisposable via inheritance from Component, so there's good odds it doesn't do anything. Of course there's no harm in using a `using` with every `IDisposable` just to be safe in case `Dispose()` does something in the future, and `try` and `catch` should have minimal overhead.

Answer (score 1):

What you should take in consideration is the fact that the using clause is used to make sure that the objects you use inside the brackets of that using clause are disposed correctly into memory.

So, I think you should use the second code example.